# Getting N/A when Trying to Import Data into Google Sheets Using XPath

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm currently trying to import the list of titles coming soon from this link:
[https://www.game.co.uk/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/HubArticle...](https://www.game.co.uk/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/HubArticleView?hubId=690759&articleId=690760&catalogId=10201&langId=44&storeId=10151&cm_mn=TopNav-_-comingSoon-_-Main)

The formula I am using is

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.game.co.uk/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/HubArticleView?hubId=690759&articleId=690760&catalogId=10201&langId=44&storeId=10151&cm_mn=TopNav-_-comingSoon-_-Main", "//*[@id='grid_to_be_filled']/div[*]/div/a/h2")
```

The XPath looks fine when I checked using XPath helper, however, when trying to import the data into Google Sheets, I just get `#N/A`.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

not possible to scrape, because it's controlled by JavaScript. all you can have is what you can see here:

[image: 0]